# How to query child elements on RavenDB?

Tags: c#, .net, database, ravendb

I'm trying querying child elements on RavenDB Embeded in .NET, text search working, but WhereBetweenOrEqual, WhereGreaterThan, WhereLessThan not working

My code :

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<Attribute> Attributes { set; get; } 
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string Key { set; get; }
    public object Value { set; get; }
}
```

Abstract Indexing class

```
public class Document_ByAttribute : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Document>
{
    public Document_ByAttribute()
    {
        Map = documents => from doc in documents
                          select new
                          {
                              _ = doc.Attributes
                                 .Select(attribute =>
                                     CreateField(attribute.Key, attribute.Value, false, true))
                          };
    }
}
```

This is Working

```
    public ActionResult Filter(string id)
    {
        var doc = _Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Document>("Document/ByAttribute").Search("Title", "*" + id + "*").ToList();
        return Json(doc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

This function is not Working

```
    public ActionResult Price_Range(decimal min = 0, decimal max = 99999999)
    {
        var doc = _Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Document>("Document/ByAttribute").WhereBetweenOrEqual("Price", min, max).ToList();
        return Json(doc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

I've tried everything. I was not successful. 
Please help me. How can do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue is the types.
You are passing a decimal, but the value on the server is interpret in some other way (likely float or int). Make sure that those match.